# How to add a ribbon at the top with css?

Tags: css, position, ribbon

I try desperately to add this little png ribbon on the top right of my page. Exactly like this one: http://www.thebestdesigns.com/

I have checked their code, but it gets messed up when I use it in mine. Take a look:

```
<style>

 html,body {
   background-color: #edecd8;

   margin:0;
   padding:0;
    height:100%;

 }

   #container {min-height:100%; position:relative;}



  #body {
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }


  a {text-decoration: none; color: black;}
  a:hover {color: #555555; border-bottom: 1px dotted black; }


#footer {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:20px;/* Height of the footer */
  background: #edecd8;
  background-image:url(pattern.png);
  text-align:center;
  font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  }


.intro {
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-variant: small-caps;
}

span.bottom {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;   }

#mytable {
padding-top:30px;
}


</style>


</head>

<body>


 <div id="container">


 <div id="body">

<center>
<table div id="mytable" width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" >
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" height="40"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="XXXX" width="100" height="30"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20" align="center" class="intro"> <a href="">online store</a> | <a href="">main website</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="352" align="center"><img src="ku.jpg" width="500" height="500"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </center>


  </div>



  <!-- Ola sto span class mporoun na xwresoun? -->
 <div id="footer"><span style class="bottom">  n@hotmail.com | the athens store | Mitropoleos 37 | t: 2xx00    </div>
 </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I tried something like that, but it gets up when I put it inside the two divs I have. What can I do? Any suggestions?

```
#ribbon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to add a position:relative to the container div?

Comment: But my container is relative!

Answer (score 6):

This is all the code you need for the ribbon:

**HTML**

```
<div id="new-themes">
    <a href="/design/themes/">Wordpress Themes</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#new-themes {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#new-themes a {
  background: url("/deck/wp-content/themes/tbd/images/ribbon-themes-red.png") no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
  text-indent: -9000px;
}
```

Be sure to place the div right in our body.

Comment: did you just copy-paste that? I tried the code from the website, but it doesnt work in my code above

Comment: Could you show us your code on a page? Or make a sample on http://cssdesk.com/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ - this would simplify our task to help you. The HTML you pasted is a bit too less, to see what you like to achieve.

Comment: take a look...Does it work on your browser? I think the prob was with an unneccesary center tag.   http://www.mysecretathens.gr/kulte_test/kulte_tabled.html